# Password validation, one regex pattern at a time

Tags: java, regex, passwords, pattern-matching

For the password field, I have a TextWatcher, and onTextChanged, i run the each of four regex patterns against the text, one at a time. My regex patterns are:

```
".{3,5}"  
"(?=.*[A-Z])"
"(?=.*[a-z])"
"(?=.*\\d)"
```

I wrote this test code and do not understand why this would fail:

```
    Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("(?=.*[A-Z])");
    Matcher mat = pat.matcher("aB");
    if(mat.matches()){
    System.out.println("MATCHES!");
    }
    else{
    System.out.println("DOES NOT MATCH");
    }
```

I expected a match here, but its failed.
Likewise other regex patterns also fail.

Comment: Please edit your question to explicitly say what behavior you get and what you expect.  (I assume you expect a match and don't get one, but I shouldn't have to guess.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With look-around `(?=condition)` we can check many conditions on entire string, because it is zero-width (it will reset position of cursor in regex engine to place where it was right before test performed by look-ahead).

So since `matches()` checks if entire string matches regex, and look-around reset cursor it means that cursor wasn't able to pass entire string to accept this regex.

If you want to use `matches()` you can use regex like this

```
(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\\d).{3,5}
```

`.{3,5}` part will allow regex engine iterate over 3-5 characters, so if string is shorter, or longer it will not be accepted (because regex wasn't able to match entire string).

Alternative to this solution is to use `find()` instead of `matches()`. Also in that case you shouldn't use look-around. Simple `[A-Z]`, `[a-z]`, `\\d` with `find()` should be fine. We use look-around mechanisms only if we want regex to be able to iterate over data more than once.

Comment: I need to be able to pattern match the password with each of regex patterns separately. Reason is, in my UI, i want to show status of each rule as password is being entered.